# my websites got infected with a malware i cannot get any info on

Tags: linux, malware, php, infection-vector

we have a server, on which we host about 30 sites.
these are test sites for our customers. most of them are not even indexed by google.

some run on php, some on nodejs, some on ruby.
all of them that run on php have been infected.

on 27 and 28 of may in a lot of directories (not only the root ones) the following where created:

consumer.php
images/config.db

the consumer.php tries to connect to 176.123.2.3.

now i could just remove them and the problem would be temporarily fixed.

but how can i find out the entry point?
i guess they used a bug in PHP (since only the PHP sites got infected)?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logs can help you determine when, what and where. If you're using Apache and a version of Unix (BSD/Linux/etc), I would start with the following:

```
tail -n 100000 /path/to/apache/logs/access_log | awk '/27\/May\/2013/'|grep 404 > 05-27-2013-404s.txt

tail -n 100000 /path/to/apache/logs/access_log | awk '/27\/May\/2013/'|grep 403 > 05-27-2013-403s.txt
```

This parses the last 100,000 entries in the access_log, parses out May 27th, then the 404s and 403s. Provided that 1) you're using Apache 2) your log format stores the dates as "27/May/2013."

From there, I would also parse out the directories from the log themselves. It is **HIGHLY LIKELY** that the first entry to hit that directory, is the responsible party for compromising your machine. You can then take the IP associated with that first entry, and go back and look at your logs to find when was the first time they showed up, what they accessed, etc.

Comment: yup, found the hole.
the first file uploaded was actually on the 26.

from 176.123.0.152, out of Moldova.

they accessed a WordPress installation, having admin/admin as login. and uploaded a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you likely don't have proper isolation between your environments.  If all your PHP scripts run as the same user then a compromise in any one of them would allow access to any portions of the system that the user PHP runs as has access to.

The best bet would be to format and rebuild your server, though if the permissions of the PHP user are limited to prevent admin access, you might be ok to simply wipe anything that that user had access to modify.  You should also make sure you move to an isolated setup so that it is easier to identify the source of intrusions.

Comment: that is true. all the php sites run under one user.